# Passing params to rails action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am using action mailer to email winners, `@result` array has records of participants who has won including their email.

```
@result=>[#<Participant id: 47, admin_id: nil, sweepstake_id: 8, participant_name: "gomez", participant_email: "rakesh.k@birdvision.in", participant_number: "12131245421", ip_addr: "127.0.0.1", answer: "nice", reg_time: nil, entry_opt_id: nil, created_at: "2015-09-03 12:15:48", updated_at: "2015-09-07 12:12:53">, #<Participant id: 47, admin_id: nil, sweepstake_id: 8, participant_name: "gomez", participant_email: "rakesh.k@birdvision.in", participant_number: "12131245421", ip_addr: "127.0.0.1", answer: "nice", reg_time: nil, entry_opt_id: nil, created_at: "2015-09-03 12:15:48", updated_at: "2015-09-07 12:12:53">]
```

But when i pass the result from my controller to the mailer, the result now only has id as string.
`Parameters: {"result"=>["47", "47"]`}.
How can i pass the array result which has all the participant records?

Code in view page:

```
<%= link_to "Email Winners",email_winner_sweepstakes_path(:result=>@result) %>
```

Code in controller:

```
def email_winner
      Rails.logger.info("***********************#{params.inspect}")
      ParticipantMailer.winner_confirmation(params[:result]).deliver_now!

  end
```

Code in mailer:

```
def winner_confirmation(result)
   @result = result
   @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
   Rails.logger.info("=================mailer=================")
   Rails.logger.info(@result.inspect)
   @result.each do |i|
   mail(to: i.participant_email, subject: 'Congratulation')
end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to find winners by ID, in this line:

```
<%= link_to "Email Winners", email_winner_sweepstakes_path(result: @result) %>
```

what you do is formulate the URL and you can't store objects its only string and what it did is it will call `.id` on `@result`

to fix that:

in your controller:

```
def email_winner
  @results = Participant.where("id in (?)", params[:result])
  ParticipantMailer.winner_confirmation(@results).deliver_now!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass ruby objects in links, because that triggers a new page load on a different URI, and the ids are provided in that address. You need to only pass ids.

Therefore your ids being passed here, you can fetch the objects with the following:

```
@result.each do |id|
  participant = Participant.find(id)
  mail(to: participant.participant_email, subject: 'Congratulation')
end
```